Weakly compact characterization
In Theorem 9.26 of Jech, it is shown that if $\kappa$ is inaccessible and has the tree property, then $\kappa \rightarrow (\kappa)^2_\lambda$ for every $\lambda<\kappa$.  Jech remarks after the proof that a similar but more complicated argument shows that $\kappa \rightarrow (\kappa)^n_\lambda$ for every finite $n$.  What is this argument?

It is not spelled out explicitely there, but there are hints and bibliographical references in 7.7 and 7.8 of Kanamori's The Higher Infinite

Let us use the Extension Property for weak compactness.  Suppose $\kappa$ is weakly compact, and let $c : [\kappa]^n \to \lambda$, where $\lambda<\kappa$.  Consider the model $\mathfrak{A} = \langle V_\kappa,\in,c\rangle$, and let $\mathfrak B = \langle M,\in,c'\rangle$ be an elementary extension such that $M$ is transitive and $\kappa \in M$.
Let $\alpha_0<\alpha_1<\dots<\alpha_{n-2}<\kappa$ be arbitrary.  By elementarity, there is $\alpha_{n-1} < \kappa$ such that $c(\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{n-2},\alpha_{n-1}) = c'(\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{n-2},\kappa)$.  Continue inductively choosing an increasing sequence $\langle \alpha_i : i < \kappa \rangle$ such that for $\beta<\kappa$ and $i_0 < \dots < i_{n-2} < \beta$, $c(\alpha_{i_0},\dots,\alpha_{i_{n-2}},\alpha_\beta) = c'(\alpha_{i_0},\dots,\alpha_{i_{n-2}},\kappa)$.  Here we the fact that this function on $[\beta]^{n-1}$ is a member of $V_\kappa$.
Now assume by induction that the result holds for $n-1$.  There is a set $H \subseteq \{ \alpha_i : i < \kappa \}$ of size $\kappa$ that is homogeneous for the function $\langle \beta_0,\dots,\beta_{n-2}\rangle \mapsto c'(\beta_0,\dots,\beta_{n-2},\kappa)$, say with value $\xi<\lambda$.  Finally, note that for any $\beta_0<\dots<\beta_{n-2}<\beta_{n-1}$ from $H$, $c(\beta_0,\dots,\beta_{n-2},\beta_{n-1}) = c'(\beta_0,\dots,\beta_{n-2},\kappa) = \xi$.
